# How to put nearly 10 images in a single row with multiple columns?

Tags: graphics, texmaker, multiple-files

I am very new to this Latex environment.

I have loaded images side by side up to 3 by `0.3\textwidth`.

But I want to put nearly 10 images in a row with multiple columns with individual caption.

For example like this

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't seem to need to label the subcaptions, so a simple strategy will work; should the need of numbering the subcaptions, using a specific command will allow to easily modify its behavior.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\column}[2]{%
  % #1 = column of images
  % #2 = caption
  \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}#1\\#2\end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  *{6}{c@{\hspace{4pt}}} % adjust to your needs (one less than the total)s
  c
  @{}
}
\column{
  \includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image-a}\\
  \includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image-b}\\
  \includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image-c}
}{GS04}
&
\column{
  \includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image-a}\\
  \includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image-b}\\
  \includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image-c}
}{NC05}
&
\column{
  \includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image-a}\\
  \includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image-b}\\
  \includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image-c}
}{TP09}
&
\column{
  \includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image-a}\\
  \includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image-b}\\
  \includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image-c}
}{QS09}
&
\column{
  \includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image-a}\\
  \includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image-b}\\
  \includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image-c}
}{GCa10}
&
\column{
  \includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image-a}\\
  \includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image-b}\\
  \includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image-c}
}{GCb10}
&
\column{
  \includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image-a}\\
  \includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image-b}\\
  \includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image-c}
}{SLIC}
\end{tabular}

\caption{Some images}

\end{figure}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

By using tikz-matrix, i have shown here 6 images in a row but you can extend it to ten images.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{center}
     \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix (M)[matrix of math nodes,left delimiter={(},right delimiter={)}]
            {
              \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; \\
              \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; \\
             \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; \\
             \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; \\
              \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; \\
            \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; \\
             };

     \end{tikzpicture}
     \end{center}
     \end{document}
```

[image]

Without delimiter use this command `left delimiter={.},right delimiter={.}` extending to 10 images in a row

```
    \documentclass{article}        
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{center}
     \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix (M)[matrix of math nodes,left delimiter={.},right delimiter={.}]
            {
              \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}};&\node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; \\
              \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}};&\node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; \\
             \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}};&\node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; \\
             \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}};&\node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; \\
              \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}};&\node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; \\
            \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}};&\node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; & \node[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{logo.jpg}}; \\
             };

     \end{tikzpicture}
     \end{center}
     \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. By the way while running the code I am getting this error:Missing } inserted;Missing \cr inserted;misplaced \cr;.Once again thank you

Comment: Why have you put the delimiters in the tikz matrix? You can do without...

Answer (score 4):

It is easy with `floatrow`, and its `(sub)floatrow` environments:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\DeclareFloatVCode{rowvsep}{\leavevmode} \renewcommand\captionskip{6pt}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[!htb]
  \setlength\columnsep{0pt}
  \captionsetup{belowskip = 20pt}
  \floatsetup[table]{rowpostcode =rowvsep, midcode = captionskip}
  \ffigbox
  {\begin{subfloatrow}[10]
      \centering
      \ffigbox[0.1\textwidth]{\caption{SN1}\label{sn1}}{\includegraphics[scale=0.18]{snark}}
      \ffigbox[0.1\textwidth]{\caption{SN2}\label{sn2}}{\includegraphics[scale=0.18]{snark}}
      \ffigbox[0.1\textwidth]{\caption{SN3}\label{sn3}}{\includegraphics[scale=0.18]{snark}}
      \ffigbox[0.1\textwidth]{\caption{SN4}\label{sn4}}{\includegraphics[scale=0.18]{snark}}
      \ffigbox[0.1\textwidth]{\caption{SN5}\label{sn5}}{\includegraphics[scale=0.18]{snark}}
      \ffigbox[0.1\textwidth]{\caption{SN6}\label{sn6}}{\includegraphics[scale=0.18]{snark}}
      \ffigbox[0.1\textwidth]{\caption{SN7}\label{sn7}}{\includegraphics[scale=0.18]{snark}}
      \ffigbox[0.1\textwidth]{\caption{SN8}\label{sn8}}{\includegraphics[scale=0.18]{snark}}
      \ffigbox[0.1\textwidth]{\caption{SN9}\label{sn9}}{\includegraphics[scale=0.18]{snark}}
      \ffigbox[0.1\textwidth]{\caption{SN10}\label{sn10}}{\includegraphics[scale=0.18]{snark}}
    \end{subfloatrow}
    \bigskip

    \begin{subfloatrow}[8]
      \centering
      \ffigbox[0.125\textwidth]{\caption{SN1}\label{h-b1}}{\includegraphics[scale=0.18]{hare-blazon}}
      \ffigbox[0.125\textwidth]{\caption{SN2}\label{h-b2}}{\includegraphics[scale=0.18]{hare-blazon}}
      \ffigbox[0.125\textwidth]{\caption{SN3}\label{h-b3}}{\includegraphics[scale=0.18]{hare-blazon}}
      \ffigbox[0.125\textwidth]{\caption{SN4}\label{h-b4}}{\includegraphics[scale=0.18]{hare-blazon}}
      \ffigbox[0.125\textwidth]{\caption{SN5}\label{h-b5}}{\includegraphics[scale=0.18]{hare-blazon}}
      \ffigbox[0.125\textwidth]{\caption{SN6}\label{h-b6}}{\includegraphics[scale=0.18]{hare-blazon}}
      \ffigbox[0.125\textwidth]{\caption{SN7}\label{h-b7}}{\includegraphics[scale=0.18]{hare-blazon}}
      \ffigbox[0.125\textwidth]{\caption{SN8}\label{h-b8}}{\includegraphics[scale=0.18]{hare-blazon}}
    \end{subfloatrow}}{\caption{The Hunting of the Snark, and a Blazon}\label{hunt}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]